# Terminate called without an active exception

Tags: c++, exception

This is my code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
using namespace std;

void func()
{
    cout<<"   func # "<<endl;
    throw;
}

int main()
{

  try
  {
      int x = -1;
      cout<<"   point 1 "<<endl;
      func();
      cout<<"   point 2 "<<endl;
  }
  catch (exception& e)
  {
      cout<<"  exception caught "<<endl;
      //throw;
  }
  cout<<"   point 3 "<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Now, it's giving this result

```
point 1
func #
terminate called after throwing an instance of in
Abort
```

But I was expecting this:

```
point 1
func #
exception caught
```

What am I missing?
Why is terminate being called like this?
And also, what if I also throw from catch block?

Comment: `throw;` needs an exception (unless you want to rethrow the currently active exception inside a `catch` block).  Inside `func()` just do `throw std::runtime_error();` and it should work.

Answer (score 8):

This is because `func` has an empty `throw` statement. If that statement is executed without an active exception being handled, terminate is *supposed* to be called.

[[expr.throw]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.throw#4)

> If no exception is presently being handled, evaluating a *throw-expression* with no operand calls std​::​​terminate().

You need to throw *something* in order to catch. An empty throw statement only has something to throw while an exception is being handled.

You probably meant to write `throw std::exception{};`

> And also, what if I also throw from catch block?

Assuming you apply the fix, the empty `throw` in the exception handler (the `catch` block) will re-throw the exception you caught from inside `func`. And now `std::terminate` will be called because an uncaught exception is about to leave the `main` function.

Comment: Thanx for quick answer. Got it.